# ORDER BY apparently not working for Datetime column?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a small table for daily logs with this schema:

```
id (int, not null)
timestamp (datetime, not null)
costcenter (int, not null)
initials (varchar(3),null)
memo (varchar(250),not null)
```

ID is a self-incrementing `Identity` column.

Here are all the data rows after I ran the query

```
SELECT id, timestamp 
FROM LOG 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

and got this as the result:

```
8   2018-12-30 10:51:08.000
7   2018-12-29 10:51:08.000
6   2018-12-13 10:51:08.000
5   2018-12-12 10:51:08.000
4   2018-01-04 08:31:00.000
3   2018-01-03 08:31:00.000
2   2018-01-02 08:45:00.000
1   2018-01-02 08:31:00.000
```

Clearly not in descending timestamp order!

If I omit the `DESC` keyword, the query results come back with the ID column in order (1-8). So it seems I am actually sorting by id, not timestamp.

Am I missing something? Is this a problem with the ID column?

Comment: Actually, it ***IS*** perfectly sorted by date **descendingly** - or which rows do you believe should be sorted differently??

Comment: Yes it is... it's sorted by Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second which is how a `DATETIME` should be sorted. Note, removing the `DESC` applies the default sort operation which is `ASC`. Judging from your schema, and the table name, I'd expect sorting by the `ID` and the `timestamp` to have the same result since the `ID` is auto-incrementing, and I assume the `timestamp` is when the record was inserted which would also always be > the previous record.

Comment: FWIW, when you omit DESC it will use the default order for an order predicate which is ASC. :) Also, be careful using timestamp as a column name. It is a datatype and using datatype names as column or object names can be really ugly to work with.

Comment: OMG the January values are supposed to be 2019, not 2018.  Totally my fault, and my apologies for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with a field called TIMESTAMP and maybe it is because is a reserved word.
I have tested in my machine and it works fine as you have shown but maybe the issue depends on the SQL Version. I would try to forze the system to identify it as a field:

```
SELECT id, [timestamp] 
FROM LOG 
ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] DESC
```

Or also:

```
SELECT id, [timestamp]
FROM LOG 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Or even:

```
SELECT id, [timestamp] AS Time_Stamp
FROM LOG 
ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT id, timestamp 
FROM LOG 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP + 1 DESC
```